# Automatically change WooCommerce order status after specific time has passed?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, status, orders

Is there any way to have WooCommerce Automatically change a custom order status to a different custom order status after so much time has passed?

Basically, I want all orders that are changed to Order Status "Refund-Submitted" be automatically get changed to "Refund-Expired" after 30 days.

I realize these are not normal WooCommerce Order Statuses, I created custom ones. So it might be easier to understand what I want if I'm less specific...

**I just want to be able to have orders that are changed to a specific status to automatically be changed to a different status after so many days.**

I looked all over the internet and have not found anything that can help me accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but for refunded orders, there is only one status: **`wc-refunded`** … but not `"Refund-Submitted"` or `"Refund-Expired"` orders status…

Comment: I created the custom order status, that is not the issue. I just want to be able to have orders that have a specific status to automatically change to a different status after so many days. I looked all over the internet and have not found anything that can help me accomplish this.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I edited my question; is that better?

Comment: Did you end up finding a way to do this? I am also looking to do the same. We created a new custom order status called "Shipped" which we put in the tracking number, but after 7 days we want it to move to be complete.

Comment: Did you found a solution mate

Comment: @SunethKalhara checkout the answer - if its not too late ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
function order_status_changer() {

    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results("
    SELECT * 
    FROM  $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
        AND post_status = 'wc-completed'
");


    $args = array(
        'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'column' => 'post_modified_gmt', // post modifed one month ago
                'after' => '1 month ago',
            ),
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_refund_expired', // skip posts that is already updated in last run
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'post_status' => 'refund-submitted', // slug of your status to modfiy
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);


    $posts = $query->posts;

    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        $ord = new WC_Order($post->ID);
        $ord->update_status('refund-expired'); // Slug to which these order to be updated
        update_post_meta($post->ID, '_refund_expired', 1); // update posts meta to note the status change for skipping on next read
    }
}
order_status_changer();
```

Add this code into theme's functions.php

Comment: Can you write solution for changing order status from processing to refunded automatically after 48 hours?

Comment: @ex501 - You may ask a new question with what you have tried. You will get the solution quickly

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into themes functions.php

You can change days ( if($int>1) ) :in this example : 1 day

( wp_ ) is table_prefix

```
add_action('init', 'wp_orders');
function wp_orders()
{

    global $wpdb;

$my_query = "SELECT * FROM wp_wc_order_stats where STATUS='wc-processing'";
        $val123 = $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT);
        $result2 = $wpdb->get_results($my_query);
        foreach ($result2 as $results2) {

            $date1 = $results2->date_created_gmt;
            $order_id = $results2->order_id;

            $date2=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

$dteStart = new DateTime($date1);
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($date2);
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd);
$Diff = $dteDiff->format("%d");
            $int = (int)$Diff;
            if($int>1)
            {
                $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
                if (!empty($order)) {
                    $order->update_status( 'completed' );
                }
            }
        }
}
```